# HLS streaming always starts from the beginning in Android Browser

Tags: android, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

### Problem

HLS streaming works well in iOS browser(real time mid-stream),

But in most of Android browser, the streaming always starts from the beginning(First Ts file when streaming started).

### Reference

- Android System：4.0,4.4,etc..
- Detail for FFmpeg command : Pull RTMP streaming, then use segment to transfer that into TS splits.

  `ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://ipaddress/live/streamname 
  -codec:a libfaac -b:a 96k -af volume=1 -ac 2 -ar 44100 
  -f segment 
  -segment_time 5 
  -segment_list_flags live 
  -segment_list /path/to/m3u8 
  -segment_format mpegts /path/to/ts`
- Detail for m3u8 file

  `#EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-VERSION:3 
   #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0 
   #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO 
   #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6 
   #EXTINF:5.000278, 
   file0000.ts 
   #EXTINF:5.013356, 
   file0001.ts4`
- HLS Player：Ckplayer + m3u8 plugins

### Help

Does anyone else meet this problem?

Comment: Is this actually a programming question?

Comment: `ffmpeg` supports `hls` directly, no need to use `segment`. Can you detail a little what do you mean by "always starts from the begining"?

Comment: Hi Aergistal. For example, If I've already streamed a movie for **30 minutes**,the android users will always start from the beginning of this movie(0'00). Actually they should start from (30'00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aergistal said in comment.
The lastest ffmpeg supports `hls` directly.
So just use `-f hls` instead of `-f segment`.
Then problem solved.

1. If we use `-f segment`

   - The value of `#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` will always be `0`.
   - Previous TS records would not be removed when latest records are added.
   - Maybe there are some parameters that I didn't know.

   So that Android devices will always start from the first TS file.
2. If we use `-f hls`

   - We can use `-hls_list_size` to define the number of TS files in m3u8 file.
   - The value of `#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE` will update automatically.

   And then it works well.

Comment: I'm using hls_list_size, but still got the same problem from android devices.

ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://server:port/address/name -rw_timeout 500 -http_persistent 1 -method PUT -http_user_agent myuseragent -f hls -hls_list_size 5 -hls_flags discont_start+delete_segments+omit_endlist -async 1 -vf "scale=640:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -movflags +faststart -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 24 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event -preset veryfast -b:v 350k -maxrate 800k -bufsize 1100k  -b:a 96k -vcodec libx264 -hls_segment_filename %03d.ts master.m3u8